# Magento 2 How to add class in product detail page?

Tags: magento2

**Theme** - Luma

**Location** - Product detail page

I would like to add my custom class along with "**column**". Please review below screenshot for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its come from this location of file path `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml` where you are able to that class `columns`. its common for all layout page.

```
            <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
            </container>
```

For only product detail page , you need to add below code in your `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns add-your-class" />
```

htmlClass="columns **add-your-class**" used for adding class for div tab in Magento2.

Comment: Hello @Yogesh, Your solution if working perfect, But It's class display all page. I have required only product detail page. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hello @Vishal , I have specified in answer , for particular product you can find your self and update answer if i will get free time i will do.

Comment: Hello @Yogesh, Thanks For Answer. Your answer is  working good.

Comment: Thank you. Don't forgot do accept & giving plus vote :)

Comment: Already voted :)

Answer (score 1):

As you want to add this class only on product view page, you have to add below code in your `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" > 
    <body> 
        <referenceContainer name="columns" htmlClass="columns customClass" />
    </body> 
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change it in following file.

```
\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\base\page_layout\empty.xml
```

However its not recommended, You could use the parent class like catalog-product-view .some-custom-class{}

Answer (score -1):

If you add below syntax for css then it will apply for product page

```
.catalog-product-view .columns {

}
```